# JPA making strange performance drops while updating db

Tags: java, performance, jpa, eclipselink, java-ee-6

I have encountered some strange behavior while inserting a lots of entities into the db. I'm getting content from 0,5GB StAX parsed XML file(contains about 35000 of entities I'm interested in), pass each JAXb binded object to EJB which insterts it into the postgres db. So far so good. First 1000 entities are persisted in about 80 ms each on avarage. When it gets to 3000 entities in total, it a little bit more, about 100 ms each. Still OK. But when I get over 7000, the problems begin. All of a sudden some entities are taking about 20 times more time than others, so for example one is persisted 150ms, the other in 3 seconds. The problem is definetly not in the size of the input object from the XML file, these are all pretty much equal.

My first thought was about flushing and clearing EntityManager, so I made this primive code:

```
if(++updateCounter % 25 == 0) {
    dao.flushAndClearContext();
    logger.info("Flushing and clearing persistance context.");
}

DAO:
public void flushAndClearContext() {
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.clear();
}
```

This didnt help. Next, out of curiosity, I copped the big XML into 5 smaller files(so about 7000 ents in one file) and tried to populate my db with one after another and it kind of worked. I could populate the db with all data in reasonable time. But the problem is still there, I still get strange behavior when persisting big numbers, only in smaller scale and it is definetly not a solution for me.

I'm using eclipselink and postgres, AS is glassfish v3.

I would appreciate and by thankful for any suggestion why this is happening and how to get rid of it.

Comment: So what's happening on the server? Show some CPU+I/O figures for the time in question. Check the logs for checkpoint-related warnings etc. Also, is this all in one transaction or in 35,000 of them? I would suspect I/O being the bottleneck.

Comment: Every insert has its own trasaction a CPU performance seems pretty constant. I'll try checking time of I/O operations though, thanks for the tip!

Comment: First step - batch your inserts together (unless you want to have individual inserts fail-able). Group them in blocks of 1,000-10,000 to see a huge improvement in performance.

Comment: Did group them into block and it worked! Thanks a lot, Sir, you just made my day!

Comment: When possible the COPY method (which I think jdbc supports) is even more efficient.